# Confusing documentation about axes in SciPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is an excerpt from SciPy [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html) (as of July 8, 2016):

> **along an axis**
>
> Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).
>
> Many operation can take place along one of these axes. For example, **we can sum each row** of an array, in which case we operate along columns, or axis 1:

```
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))    
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> x.sum(axis=1)
array([ 6, 22, 38])
```

I think there is a mistake because **they are summing not all rows, but all columns** and hence they use `axis = 1` because they iterate through all columns (i.e. move horizontally along axis 1) and add them up.

So, my question is: is this a mistake in documentation or do I not understand how axes work in SciPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example.

```
>>> print(a)
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

To sum over columns:

```
>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([18, 22, 26])
```

Or, to sum over rows:

```
>>> a.sum(axis=1)
array([ 3, 12, 21, 30])
```

I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Now I see: when they say *sum each row* they actually mean the sum of all elements of the row for each row, and not summing all rows (this is how I initially interpreted the phrase). So basically they are adding columns of a given matrix and they indeed move along the horizontal axis, or along columns, and this is why they use `axis = 1`.